# Можно ли перенести папку ProgramData/Microsoft/VisualStudio?

Tags: windows, файловая-система

Проверил сколько весит эта папка у меня на SSD, и немного пришел в шок. Можно ли как-то ее перенести на другой диск, чтобы при этом ничего не сломалось?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перенести каталог на другой диск. Создать символическую ссылку на каталог в папке Microsoft. Можно с помощью утилиты **mklink**.

Comment: @Daemon-5 можете подробно расписать как это сделать? Буду вам очень, очень благодарен

Comment: А что в ней находится? У меня установленно куча всего, но эта папка только ~80МБ.

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows 10 запустить **cmd.exe** (от Администратора)

```
cd /d c:\programdata&mkdir "Microsoft Visual Studio"& robocopy "Microsoft Visual Studio" "d:\Microsoft Visual Studio" /e /is /move&mklink /j "Microsoft Visual Studio" "d:\Microsoft Visual Studio"
```

или построчно для Win7-10 - **cmd.exe** (от Администратора):

```
cd /d %ProgramData%
set "mvDIR=Microsoft Visual Studio"
xcopy "%mvDIR%" "d:\%mvDIR%"  /e /i /k /o /x
rmdir "%mvDIR%" /s /q
mklink /j "%mvDIR%" "d:\%mvDIR%"
```